Extending a k-uniform hypergraph
Let $H = (V, E)$ be a $k$-uniform hypergraph of order $n = \vert V \vert$ and size $ t = \vert E \vert$ < Bin(n,k). Assume that for any vertex cover $C$ in $H$, we have $\vert C \vert \ll n$.
I would like to have an upper bound on the size of a $(k+1)$-uniform hypergraph $H' = (V, E')$ such that $H'$ contains $H$. In the sense that for any $e \in E$, there exits $e' \in E'$ such that $e \subset e'$ and conversely, for any $e' \in E'$ there exists $e \in E$ such that $e \subset e'$.
Any references would be greately helpful.

Can you say what kind of upper bound you are after? I think t is the best general upper bound you can hope for. You can save edges in H' any time there are multiple edges in H which live on a set of k+1 vertices.

I updated the question. As what interests me is to assume that there are many "free" vertices in H. In which case t does not seem adequate.
